# What would be the example of a 2D crosd correlation?

Tags: cross-correlation

1D cross correlation is the correlation between two 1D vectors. 2D cross correlation is the correlation between two 2D matrices

I was reading [**this link**](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/correlation.html) which talks about 1D cross correlation.

Can anyone provide me a real-life example of a 2D cross correlation, and show me how can I **manually** calculate a 2D cross correlation?

---

To my understanding,

[image]

These types of **two** plots can be used to calculate 2D correlation.

---

N.B. kindly, don't use an example from image processing.

Comment: What do you mean by 1D & 2D correlation?

Comment: So you mean [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) not "2D correlation". Please edit to make it clear since there is no such a thing as "2D correlation".

Comment: No. Correlation, auto-correlation and cross-correlation are three different things. If you want to read what correlation is, here is a good starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_coefficient

Comment: @Tim, The Cambridge Dictionary of Statistics, 4th Ed, 2010, Everitt, Skrondal, Page - 107.........  doesn't agree with your notion.

Comment: This discussion leads nowhere. You are using the terminology in ambiguous way. Your link describes the Pearson's correlation coefficient while your question refers to cross correlation, those are different concepts. This makes your question unclear. I doubt that the Cambridge Dictionary of Statistics describes Pearson's correlation as cross-correlation.